# Mean squared error returning unreasonably high numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict the profit each film made on IMDb.

My dataframe and features are as follows:

```
   Actor1  Actor2  Actor3  Actor4   Day  Director  Genre1  Genre2  Genre3  \
0       0       0       0       0  19.0         0       0       0       0   
1       1       1       1       1   6.0         1       1       1       1   
2       2       2       2       2  20.0         2       0       2       2   
3       3       3       3       3   9.0         3       2       0      -1   
4       4       4       4       4   9.0         4       3       3       3   

   Language  Month  Production  Rated  Runtime  Writer    Year    BoxOffice  

0         1      0           0      0    118.0       0  2007.0   37500000.0  

1         2      1           1      0    151.0       1  2006.0  132300000.0  

2         1      1           2      1    130.0       2  2006.0   53100000.0  

3         1      2           1      0    117.0       3  2007.0  210500000.0  

4         4      3           3      2    117.0       4  2006.0  244052771.0
```

and the value I'm trying to predict (target) is the BoxOffice.

I'm following documentation for sklearn exactly as it is (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score

X = dataset[:,0:16] # Features
Y = dataset[:,16] #Target

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.33)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
mean_squared_error(Y_test, regr.predict(X_test))
```

and the output is always something along the lines of:  **11385650623660550** ($11,385,650,623,660,500.00)

While the mean of the BoxOffice is:
107989121

etc.

Ive tried multiple different approaches, cross-validation as well as other models (keras) and feel like I've tried everything.

The returning sum is extremely high which makes me question that the problem is not in the model or the data, but something else that I'm missing.

Comment: it seems like your model is always guessing 0 which leads to very high MSE. The square root of the error value you provided is right around your stated average.

Comment: Hello, I dont think that is the case because if i print individual preidcitions: a = regr.predict(X_test)
print(a[0]) I get for example this: 96267029

Comment: maybe your model is just really bad :( MSE is pretty easy to calculate, you could confirm the output of `mean_squared_error` yourself to verify. That error matches the order of magnitude for your data. Not unreasonably high considering the data and assuming a horrible model.

Comment: As in, there is nothing to learn from the data? nothing correlates with the boxoffice? Wouldn't I at worst be able to overfit my model for my data and get some sort of accuracy?

Comment: the fact that your current model is not doing well doesn't mean there is nothing to learn. You can generate perfectly linear data and still generate plenty of models that have horrible error rates. It just means something needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, your problem is not related with mean squared error, it is model itself.

For your categorical features, I recommend you to try another encode method like OneHotEncoder. LabelEncoder is not good option for lineer regression.

(For more information: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)

Before train your model, take a look correlation of your numeric features with your target variable maybe some of them irrelevant, for categorical features you can try different methods to analyze their relationship with your target variables (like boxplots)

Lineer regression need continuous variables so you may want to try other algorithms as well. Just make sure that you have the enough background before apply them.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll give it a go and see if I get a better result. My question is though, why wouldn't OneHotEncoding be better in every case? What is a case where we want categorical data encoded and at the same time treat them as a numeric value? (dates?)

Comment: It depends on the case which encode method is good. Labelencode may be used for cases like {Yes,No} = {1,0} or if categorical variables can be classified hierarchically {Good,Average,Bad} = {3,2,1} (These are just examples other cases may need different approaches)
Lastly, why this encode method is not suitable for lineer regressin
Lets say English=4 and Spanish=1 and lineer regression equation is y=ax1+...+c
Eng: y=4a+...+c
Span: y=1a+...+c
when language is eng y (target variable) will be more since it is 4 when other features same which isn't logical, hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try standardizing your output (or Y) variables and bringing them between 0 and 1.

Comment: That somewhat improved the result, but I don't understand why? Don't we standardize the data so that in relation to the other data it is all on the same "scale", but if i only have one type of data what is the benefit?

Comment: if you normalize your data you will also be normalizing your MSE. You are saying that normalizing improved your error beyond what you would expect?

Comment: This is not necessarily true. You can use transform the data and then inverse-transform it back using MinMaxScaler. Check this out: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: Yes thats what I did, inverse-transform the MSE. Which landed me from a MSE of 0.0100734 to  $9,438,990.00 , which is a reasonable result.

Answer (score -3):

can you check the accuracy of your model? I guess it's very low hence you are getting high mean squared error.Because of low accuracy of model difference between predicted box office and actual is very high and squaring it becomes even bigger.

`rgr.score(X_test,Y_test`)